# Need to add 45+ points to a google map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, limits

trying to add 45 different points to a map, but I just get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` returned, and no map.

I am getting locations via a string search, then assigning the returned LatLng object to a new google Marker object

---

*String Search*

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': x}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var result = results[0].geometry.location;
          return result;

        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
```

Comment: <http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/usage.html> ?

Comment: how are you getting the string searchs?

Comment: geocoding only is allowed by 2500 searchs per day or if you do 45 points, 2500/45 = 55 times before it would stop you. unless you have the bussiness version u get 100000 http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: but it is still letting me run maps from the same domain, from the same machine!

Comment: it doesn't stop you from using the map, just the geocode.

Comment: but the over points are geocoded too!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6702/discussion-between-l7colwinters-and-mild-fuzz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Geocoding is rate limited throughout the day. It's also limited by IP address. So, two possible interactions: If you're sharing an IP address with lots of other people, they may also be dragging down your quota. This is particularly true in mobile environments. Another more likely possibility is that you are running into the rate limit over the day. If you get that, pause of a second or two and try again.

You can also cache geocodes and addresses for performance purposes, and have a back-up server side geocoding service using Google's web services. That'll also be quota'd but it's a good fallback.

Comment: First thing I would try is using setTimeout or equivalent to space out your request by 2-3 seconds. Your likely being throttled for not spacing out your requests.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Google Fusion Tables for the data storage and its geocoding part- at the very least, their batch geocoding interface obeys their own internal limits.

http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012281

Answer (score 0):

How you should approach this is by geocoding the static address, if they are static and save the lat lng for further use. I don't know what to say if there not static tho.